# How do I unit test a function that fires an Ajax call in jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

For example something like this

```
func do something()
{
api.ajax('') //Ajax call that triggers inside the function
.done(response){
do something with response
}
}
```

How do I get to expect something from the response and make my assertions? ANy help would be really helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to test if the ajax response correctly or you want to test the callback function?

Comment: you need [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax)

Comment: @crystalwill In my function to be tested, I actually manipulate the response and do something with it so I want to test if the response was changed after my Ajax call

Comment: i've updated the answer a little bit to be closer to use case you've specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jasmine-ajax in tests looks like this:

```
describe('Sample test', function(){

    var request = function(arg){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            $.ajax({
                method:'GET',
                url: 'example.com/api/'+arg,
                success: function(response){
                    resolve(changeResponse(response));
                },
                error: reject
            });
        });

        function changeResponse(response){
            return response.key + '-changed';
        }
    };

    var TestResponses = {
        someEndPoint: {
            success: {
                status: 200,
                responseText: '{"key":"value"}'
            }
        }
    };

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
    });

    it('can be called with for some end-point', function(){
        spyOn($, 'ajax');
        request('something');
        expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
        var actualAjaxOptions = $.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
        expect(actualAjaxOptions).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
            method:'GET',
            url: 'example.com/api/something',
        }));
    });

    it('modifies response as expected', function(done){
        request('something').then(function(){
            expect(arguments[0]).toEqual('value-changed');
            done();
        }, function(reason){
            done.fail();
        });
        jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith(TestResponses.someEndPoint.success);
    });
})
```

Pleas note that:

> jasmine-ajax is currently compatible with any library that uses
>   XMLHttpRequest. Tested with jQuery and Zepto.

(from [docs](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax#libraries-supported))

Comment: I will take a look at it and get back to this post